# (xfce4-terminal) Failed to connect to the session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined

Tags: lxsession

I'm a newbie of both Linux/Raspberry Pi/X Window system. So this might be a dumb question, but I'm having a problem of seeing the following warning message when xfce4-terminal is launched from PuTTY + ssh connection + VcXsrc.exe on my PC.

```
(xfce4-terminal:10358): GLib-WARNING **: (/build/glib2.0-tTvduh/glib2.0-2.42.1/./glib/gerror.c:381):g_error_new_valist: runtime check failed: (domain != 0)
Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
```

My raspberry pi OS is Raspbian Jessie Lite. I have no plan to connect it to monitor nor input device, so I just install X11 client programs and libraries only, and lunch programs from ssh connection.

So far, it just displays the warning message. Is there a fix for this message or can I ignore it safely?

By the way, I'd like to use xfce4-terminal because it can switch display language easily. I'm a Japanese, so want to read some old Japanese encoded documents occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me and was a basic solution.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xrdp 

$ sudo service xrdp start
```

Try do a Remote Connection.

I think was enough. :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a session manager if you don't use a desktop environment and just start individual GUI programs via SSH. The whole concept of a session is designed to give a user which is logged in locally a certain exclusive control over the computer: that user will be the one who decides what the HDMI screen resolution should be, when a screensaver should start or what programs should play audio on the speakers.

I'm not sure what `xfce-terminal` needs the session for. Perhaps it wants to terminate gracefully when the user holding the session logs out, instead of just killing whatever programs you run in it. Unless you install a desktop environment, you won't be able to "log out" of your session anyway.