# How to set the SESSION_MANAGER environment variable?

Tags: linux, raspbian-jessie

I'm designing a GUI app using wxWidgets. My requirement is to open an image from within the app. For that I'm calling `wxTheMimeTypesManager->GetFileTypeFromExtension(wxT("png"))`. Unfortunately, this is throwing an error telling `Failed to connect to the session manager: SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined`.

I went through the solution provided [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54751/xfce4-terminal-failed-to-connect-to-the-session-manager-session-manager-envir) but it was of no help. Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated.

Even when I do a `echo $SESSION_MANAGER` it turns out to be empty.

[EDIT]Currently using wXWidgets version 3.0.2 on Jessie

Comment: This question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: You should specify the version of wxWidgets you are using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [fix](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/00d8434156178e9e02cb733e4abb61d62a0dd913) which hides this error when `$SESSION_MANAGER` is not defined, so one solution would be to upgrade to the latest version of wxWidgets.

You could also install a session manager, but only do so if you need one.